# Issues getting percentage and count of duplicates in table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to end up with something like this, but the logic is evading me

```
SELECT entity_id
     , customer_email
FROM sales_flat_order;
```

Displays as you can imagine several email addresses, some of them dupes some unique.

I had figured I could do something like this to get the counts (unsuccessfully though)

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT customer_email)) AS 'All Orders'
     , (COUNT(DISTINCT customer_email) - COUNT(SELECT customer_email FROM sales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_email HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS 'Single Orders'
     , (COUNT(DISTINCT customer_email) - COUNT(SELECT customer_email FROM hubsales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS 'Repeat Orders'
FROM sales_flat_order;
```

Even after this gets working, it would be fairly complex after trying to get a percentage. How can I best handle this, and best fix the query?

The error I get for my query currently is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT customer_email FROM sales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_email HAVIN' at line 2
```

**EDIT**

I've gotten this far on my sql query but end up with an error

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT customer_email)) AS 'All Orders'

     , ( COUNT(DISTINCT customer_email) - (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(SELECT customer_email FROM hubsales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_email HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS 's')
       ) AS 'Single Orders'

     , ( COUNT(DISTINCT customer_email) - (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(SELECT customer_email FROM hubsales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS 'r')
       ) AS 'Repeat Orders'

FROM hubsales_flat_order;
```

Error is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''s')
   ) AS 'Single Orders'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty tangled, but here it is

```
SELECT 'All Orders' AS 'Type'
       , (
            SELECT COUNT(customer_email) FROM foodhubsales_flat_order
         ) AS 'Count'

       , CONCAT(
            ROUND(
            (
                SELECT COUNT(customer_email) FROM foodhubsales_flat_order
            ) / (
                SELECT COUNT(customer_email) FROM foodhubsales_flat_order
            ) * 100, 1), '%') AS 'Percentage'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Single Orders' AS 'Type'
       , (
            COUNT(
                DISTINCT customer_email
            ) - (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(
                    SELECT customer_email FROM foodhubsales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                ) s
            )
         ) AS 'Count'

       , CONCAT(
            ROUND(
            (

            COUNT(
                DISTINCT customer_email
            ) - (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(
                    SELECT customer_email FROM foodhubsales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                ) s
            )
         ) / (
                SELECT COUNT(customer_email) FROM foodhubsales_flat_order
         ) * 100, 1), '%') AS 'Percentage'

FROM foodhubsales_flat_order

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Repeat Orders' AS 'Type'
       , (
            COUNT(
                customer_email
            ) - (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(
                    SELECT customer_email FROM foodhubsales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_email HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                ) s
            )
         ) AS 'Count'

       , CONCAT(
            ROUND(
            (

            COUNT(
                customer_email
            ) - (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(
                    SELECT customer_email FROM foodhubsales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_email HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                ) s
            )
         ) / (
                SELECT COUNT(customer_email) FROM foodhubsales_flat_order
         ) * 100, 1), '%') AS 'Percentage'

FROM foodhubsales_flat_order;
```